# How to get the pointer of a block of a matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am using Eigen library in C++ .

My question is:
I have a fixed sized matrix A , Now I want to pass the pointer of a block of A (`A.block(0,0,flag,flag)` ) into a function.
For example:

```
 int flag = 2;
 Eigen::Matrix<int,3,3> A;
 A<<1,2,3
    4,5,6
    7,8,9;
```

So I passed `A.block(0,0,flag,flag).data()` into the function but obviously when the function reads the values the reading order is still `1,2,3,4,......`, but what I want is `1,2,4,5`.

I think one way to achieve this is to create a dynamic matrix(B)(`flag` is not constant) to store the block of A, then pass the `B.data()` into the function. However, I had better not use dynamic matrix in my program.

I think another way is to fill the block as rows in the matrix and then pass `A.data()` into the function, as the following figure shows:

[image]

Can I use any faster/better operations instead of loops(because of big size of the matrix) to construct this or is there other way to pass the pointer of a block of a matrix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the order of values in which you are populating your matrix is what should be expected. You are storing the values `[1,9]` in sequential order. So when you try to retrieve these values from the matrix, that is what you are getting. I'm not very familiar with Eigen as I've only used it a couple of times, but there might be some functionality within their API that may allow you to retrieve data either by column or row-major ordering as well as transposed, inverse (if valid), identity and other valid matrix properties. You may want to read a little more into their documentation.

Comment: As for using faster/better operations instead of loops, depending on the size of the matrix, you could possibly use a stacked based buffer that will utilize locality and minimize cache misses. Also, depending on the compiler you are using and the architect of your system, you may even use inline assembly to use the vectorized registers and vectorized instructions also commonly called vector intrinsics. There are some Youtube channels and videos that provide examples, javidx9, Jason Turner, and others which can be found here https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=C%2B%2B+vector+intrinsics

Comment: I left the above as comments and didn't provide them as an actual answer since they appear to be relatively opinion-based as there are several ways to achieve the functionality that you are looking for. Due to this, I provided them as comments to help give you aid to guide you in finding a solution that is appropriate for your specific problem. Here's another search query: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=c%2B%2B+AVX+and+SIMD+instructions

Comment: The pointer points to a solid memory. A block is not solid memory. In general, you cannot join these things. You can either add support of strides or indirect indexing to a function, where you pass a pointer, or pass block (why cannot  you just pass block to the function?) or copy the block elements to a solid memory storage.

Comment: Your function could accept `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXi>` instead of `int *`. Not sure what "the function" is supposed to do, though (hint: provide a [mre]!)